# Swift 2.2: creating random playlist for AVAudioPlayer

Tags: ios, swift, random, avaudioplayer, playlist

I am trying to create a random playlist of 4 items from a bank of sounds that the user is able to play/pause, skip forwards, and skip backwards through.

I'm new to both Swift and object-orientated programming (sorry!). Currently using Xcode 7.3.1.

My code:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

var E1Audio: AVPlayerItem?
var E2Audio: AVPlayerItem?
var E3Audio: AVPlayerItem?
var E4Audio: AVPlayerItem?
var E5Audio: AVPlayerItem?
var E6Audio: AVPlayerItem?

struct playlist {
    var initialitems: [AVPlayerItem] = []
    var shuffleditems: [AVPlayerItem] {
     initialitems.shuffle
    }
    var instanceplaylist: [AVPlayerItem]{
     shuffleditems[0...3]
    }
}

var EnvPlaylist: [AVPlayerItem] = playlist(initialitems: [E1Audio, E2Audio, E3Audio, E4Audio, E5Audio, E6Audio])
let EnvPlayer = AVPlayer()
var currentTrack = 0

@IBAction func envPreviousTrack() {
    if currentTrack-1 < 0 {
        currentTrack = (EnvPlaylist.count - 1) < 0 ? 0 : (EnvPlaylist.count - 1)
    } else {
        currentTrack-1
    }
}

@IBAction func envNextTrack() {
    if currentTrack+1 > EnvPlaylist.count {
        currentTrack = 0
    } else {
        currentTrack+1;
    }
}

@IBAction func envPlayTrack() {
    if EnvPlaylist.count > 0 {
        EnvPlayer.replaceCurrentItemWithPlayerItem(InstancePlaylist2[currentTrack])
        EnvPlayer.play()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
let E1Audio = AVPlayerItem.init(URL: NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("E1Audio", withExtension: "wav")!)
let E2Audio = AVPlayerItem.init(URL: NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("E2Audio", withExtension: "wav")!)
let E3Audio = AVPlayerItem.init(URL: NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("E3Audio", withExtension: "wav")!)
let E4Audio = AVPlayerItem.init(URL: NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("E4Audio", withExtension: "wav")!)
let E5Audio = AVPlayerItem.init(URL: NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("E5Audio", withExtension: "wav")!)
let E6Audio = AVPlayerItem.init(URL: NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("E6Audio", withExtension: "wav")!)

    }
}
}
```

This gives the error: instance member 'E1Audio' cannot be used on type 'ViewController'.

If I move the declaration of EnvPlaylist to viewDidLoad() then I'm unable to define the functions envPreviousTrack(), envNextTrack(), and envPlayTrack() at the class level to then link to my UI buttons.

How can I get around this? Thanks in advance. Sorry if it's a dumb question.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot directly declare variables like that. Do this:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var E1Audio = AVPlayerItem()
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()   
        E1Audio = AVPlayerItem.init(URL: NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("E1Audio", withExtension: "wav")!)
    }
}
```

Repeat this with all of your audio items.

Comment: Thanks. Have updated the question to reflect changes; still getting the same error in Xcode?

Comment: @OliverMcCallion in the viewDidLoad method, remove the let before E1Audio. You do not want to recreate the variable.